# TikZ circuits: symbol for gas discharge tube?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-circuit-lib

In the TikZ circuit library, is there a symbol for a gas discharge tube?

In the manual I could not find anything regarding this (and the whole symbol list in there seems rather short, anyways).

Comment: Nope, you will have to create your own. As with many other symbols.

Comment: Is there any other package that provides better (meaning: more complete) circuit drawing functionality?

Comment: You can try [circuitikz](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/circuitikz), but for specific things the manual way is required.

Comment: There is `circuitikz`, but I'm not sure it contains any gas discharge tube...

Comment: I read somewhere that TikZ's circuit library outranks `circuitikz`? How can this be if it doesn't provide all symbols?

Comment: May you provide an example of such symbol?

Comment: For example there: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Neon_lamp_schematics.svg

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two things are required to get Lionel's node to work like the other circuit components: You need to declare the symbol using `circuit declare symbol=<name>, set <name> graphic={shape=<shape name>, draw, transform shape,...}`, and you need to construct the shape around the local origin.

Here's one way of doing this (note that I used the `circle ee` shape as the basis for the new symbol, because it already defines the `input` and `output` anchors.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits, shapes.gates.ee}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\pgfdeclareshape{neon lamp shape}
{
    \inheritsavedanchors[from=circle ee]
    \inheritanchor[from=circle ee]{center}
    \inheritanchor[from=circle ee]{north}
    \inheritanchor[from=circle ee]{south}
    \inheritanchor[from=circle ee]{east}
    \inheritanchor[from=circle ee]{west}
    \inheritanchor[from=circle ee]{north east}
    \inheritanchor[from=circle ee]{north west}
    \inheritanchor[from=circle ee]{south east}
    \inheritanchor[from=circle ee]{south west}
    \inheritanchor[from=circle ee]{input}
    \inheritanchor[from=circle ee]{output}
    \inheritanchorborder[from=circle ee]

    \backgroundpath{
        \pgf@process{\radius}
        \pgfutil@tempdima=\radius

        \pgfpathcircle{\centerpoint}{\pgfutil@tempdima}

        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{-\pgfutil@tempdima}{0pt}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{-0.2\pgfutil@tempdima}{0pt}}
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{-0.2\pgfutil@tempdima}{0.7\pgfutil@tempdima}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{-0.2\pgfutil@tempdima}{-0.7\pgfutil@tempdima}}

        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgfutil@tempdima}{0pt}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0.2\pgfutil@tempdima}{0pt}}
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{0.2\pgfutil@tempdima}{0.7\pgfutil@tempdima}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0.2\pgfutil@tempdima}{-0.7\pgfutil@tempdima}}
        \pgfusepath{stroke}

        \pgfpathcircle{\pgfqpoint{-0.4\pgfutil@tempdima}{-0.55\pgfutil@tempdima}}{.075\pgfutil@tempdima}
        \pgfusepath{fill}
    }
}
\makeatother


\begin{tikzpicture}[
circuit,
circuit declare symbol=neon lamp,
set neon lamp graphic={shape=neon lamp shape, draw, minimum size=1cm,transform shape}
]
\draw (0,0) to [neon lamp] (2,1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks; for my information, are this kind of information in the Tikz manual?

Comment: @LionelMANSUY: The part about `circuit declare symbol`: Yes (section 29.2 "The Base Circuit Library"). The part about having to define the shape around the centre point: No (or I didn't find it), I deduced that from the offset that results otherwise.

Comment: @Jack: is `circuit declare symbol` only related to *circuits*? I mean, I have started to make a small set of chemical process symbols (valve, pumps, ...). May I use such command to place valve for example?

Comment: @LionelMANSUY: Yes, that'll work as well. You just need to make sure to use `\begin{tikzpicture}[circuit]` to activate that functionality.

Comment: @Jake, the little circle should be filled.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a node; it is based upon the circle shape, so you can set its size with the `minimum width` key.

It is not yet finished (I was not able to use it with the `to[...]` syntax, and I probably need some advices, because I don't really know how to make this)

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\pgfdeclareshape{neon lamp}
{
    \inheritsavedanchors[from=circle]
    \inheritanchor[from=circle]{center}
    \inheritanchor[from=circle]{north}
    \inheritanchor[from=circle]{south}
    \inheritanchor[from=circle]{east}
    \inheritanchor[from=circle]{west}
    \inheritanchor[from=circle]{north east}
    \inheritanchor[from=circle]{north west}
    \inheritanchor[from=circle]{south east}
    \inheritanchor[from=circle]{south west}
    \inheritanchorborder[from=circle]
    \anchor{input}{\pgf@process{\radius} \pgf@x=\z@ \pgf@y=\radius}
    \anchor{output}{\pgf@process{\radius} \pgf@y=\radius \pgf@x=2\pgf@y}

    \backgroundpath{
        \pgf@process{\radius}
        \pgfutil@tempdima=\radius

        \pgfpathcircle{\pgfqpoint{\pgfutil@tempdima}{\pgfutil@tempdima}}{\pgfutil@tempdima}

        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\z@}{\pgfutil@tempdima}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{.8\pgfutil@tempdima}{\pgfutil@tempdima}}
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{.8\pgfutil@tempdima}{1.7\pgfutil@tempdima}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{.8\pgfutil@tempdima}{.3\pgfutil@tempdima}}

        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{2\pgfutil@tempdima}{\pgfutil@tempdima}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{1.2\pgfutil@tempdima}{\pgfutil@tempdima}}
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{1.2\pgfutil@tempdima}{1.7\pgfutil@tempdima}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{1.2\pgfutil@tempdima}{.3\pgfutil@tempdima}}

        \pgfpathcircle{\pgfqpoint{.55\pgfutil@tempdima}{.4\pgfutil@tempdima}}{.05\pgfutil@tempdima}
    }
}
\makeatother


\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[shape=neon lamp,draw] (lamp) {};
\draw (lamp.input) -- ++(-.5,0);
\draw (lamp.output) -- ++(.5,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

## A PSTricks Solution

I realize this question has long been forgotten. I also realize OP asked about Tikz, but still, it may be useful to have a PSTricks solution available in this context.

With `pst-circ` we have the settings and the mechanism to use: `\newCircDipole`. For example:

```
\newCircDipole{neonlamp}%
\makeatletter%
\def\pst@draw@neonlamp{%
  \pscircle(0,0){0.5}
  \psline[linewidth=2\pslinewidth](-0.15,-0.3)(-0.15, 0.3)
  \psline[linewidth=2\pslinewidth](0.15,-0.3)(0.15, 0.3)
  \psdot[dotsize=0.1](0,0.3)
  \wire(-0.6,0)(-0.15,0)
  \wire(0.6,0)(0.15,0)
  \pnode(-0.6,0){dipole@1}
  \pnode(0.6,0){dipole@2}%
}%
\makeatother
```

[image: neonlamp]